# How to count the occurrences of a letter in a String without duplication in printing?

Tags: java, arrays, string, cpu-word, charat

Please run the code if possible

**input:** "wooooow"
**output:** 
w:2
o:5
o:5
o:5
o:5
o:5
w:2

I want the results to be : **w:2 o:5**

I have tried several ifs and loops to make it happen but I can't is there a syntax for it? or anything

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main( String[] args ){

        String sWord= new String();
        int nCtr,nCtr2,nTemp=0,n,n1=0,n2=0,n3=0;
        char cTemp=' ',cTemp2=' ';      
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Word");
        sWord = input.nextLine();
        n = sWord.length();
        char[] cArray = new char[n];
        cArray = sWord.toCharArray();

        for(int ctr=cArray.length;ctr>0;ctr--){
            for(nCtr=0;nCtr<cArray.length;nCtr++){
                if(cArray[nCtr]==sWord.charAt(n1)){     
                    nTemp++;
                }
            }//for


            cTemp = cArray[n2];


            for(nCtr2=0;nCtr2<n;nCtr2++){
                if(sWord.charAt(nCtr2)=='$'){       
                    n3++;
                } 
            }//for

            System.out.println("# of occurence of " + cTemp + " is " + nTemp);

            n1++;
            n2++;   
            nTemp=0;
        }//for minus        


    }//

}//class
```

Comment: Use a data structure that disallows duplicate entries. The ideal structure here is a kind of HashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        String sWord= new String();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Word");
        sWord = input.nextLine();

        HashMap<Character, Integer> charCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        for(Character c : sWord.toCharArray()) {
            if(charCount.containsKey(c)) {
                charCount.put(c, charCount.get(c)+1);
            } else {
                charCount.put(c, 1);
            }
        }

        for(Character key : charCount.keySet()) {
            System.out.print(key + ":" + charCount.get(key) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

This will print the following lines:

Enter a Word

wooooow

w:2 o:5

Should work for Uppercase, Lowercase, Numbers, ... everything you can save in a String.

edit:
Without using a HashMap:

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
        String sWord= new String();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Word");
        sWord = input.nextLine();

        int[] cArr = new int[1024];

        for(char c : sWord.toCharArray()) {
            if((int) c <= cArr.length) {
                cArr[(int) c]++;
            }
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < cArr.length; x++) {
            if(cArr[x] > 0) {
                System.out.print((char) x + ":" + cArr[x]);
            }
        }
    }
```

This works because you can cast a char to an integer and use it as an index for the array. Also you can do this reverse integer -> char.

This will work for the first 1024 Chars in your Charset. Normaly theese are all uppercase, lowercase, numbers and special characters.

Comment: Wow I like how well the code works! if its not a bother how does the hashmap work?

Comment: The HashMap is a Key-Value-Storage. You always have a Key (in this case a Character) and use this key to get a Value (in this case an Integer). If this Key is already available it will be used to get the Value, add 1 to it and put it back to the HashMap. If not, it will be put in the HashMap with 0 as Value.

Comment: You don't need to define `int[] cArr = new int[1024];` array of 1024, even 26 will be good as the input will be chars only.

Comment: Not in this case. If you use the ASCII-Key as an index for the array, like in my example, you would save the lowercase 'a' at index 97. The Array with 26 won't work here. You need at least a size of 123 to save the chars till lowercase 'z'. I don't know very much about charsets. So I used 1024 to avoid Exceptions. Also maybe you should save Lowercase and Uppercase. So you would minimum need 52 ints.

Answer (score 0):

This answer works only for lowercase input. For uppercase as well, use an array of size 46.

You will have to keep track of the occurrences yourself by creating a new array or some other data structure. Also, I dont think that your loops are very efficient.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temp {
  public static void main( String[] args ){

    String sWord= new String();
    int nCtr,nCtr2,nTemp=0,n,n1=0,n2=0,n3=0;
    char cTemp=' ',cTemp2=' ';
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a Word");
    sWord = input.nextLine();
    n = sWord.length();
    char[] cArray = new char[n];
    cArray = sWord.toCharArray();

    int[] countsOfChars = new int[26];

    for(int ctr=cArray.length;ctr>0;ctr--){
      for(nCtr=0;nCtr<cArray.length;nCtr++){
        if(cArray[nCtr]==sWord.charAt(n1)){
          nTemp++;
        }
      }//for


      cTemp = cArray[n2];


      for(nCtr2=0;nCtr2<n;nCtr2++){
        if(sWord.charAt(nCtr2)=='$'){
          n3++;
        }
      }//for

//      System.out.println("# of occurence of " + cTemp + " is " + nTemp);
      countsOfChars[cTemp - 'a'] = nTemp;

      n1++;
      n2++;
      nTemp=0;
    }//for minus

    for(int i=0; i<26; i++){
      if(countsOfChars[i] != 0) {
        System.out.println("# of occurence of " + (char)('a'+i) + " is " + countsOfChars[i]);
      }
    }


  }//

}//class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
            string str = "wooooow";
            Dictionary<char, int> table = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            foreach (char ch in str.ToCharArray())
            {
                int count = 0;
                if (table.TryGetValue(ch, out count))
                {
                    table[ch] = count + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    table.Add(ch, 1);
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in table)
            {
                Console.Write(item.Key + ":" + item.Value+"  ");
            }
```

Comment: Before i could paste this solution, @xudabit already pasted his answer